# Options not passing through class file with \LoadClass command

Tags: koma-script, document-classes, books, documentclass-writing, class-options

The following code works fine and gives expected output.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{wordlike}
\usepackage{blindtext,setspace}
\geometry{hmargin=2.54cm,vmargin=2.54cm}
\setstretch{1.09}
\begin{document}
\noindent\blindtext[9]
\end{document}
```

I want to convert it to class file. Following is the class-file based on above code.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}
\LoadClass[fontsize=14pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[none]{hyphenat}
\RequirePackage{scrextend}
\RequirePackage{wordlike}
\RequirePackage{blindtext,setspace}
\geometry{hmargin=2.54cm,vmargin=2.54cm}
\setstretch{1.09}
```

When I compile the code in `my.tex` file (given below), it gets compiled.

```
\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{document}
\noindent\blindtext[9]
\end{document}
```

However the options `fontsize=14pt` and probably other options are not passed. So the problem is that `\LoacClass` doesn't seem to pass options to tex file. How can this issue be addressed? I also found that if I use `\documentclass[fontsize=14pt,twoside,a4paper]{myclass}`, the issue gets solved. But I want to load `myclass` with options specified. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of using the code 'directly', the option `fontsize=14bp` isn't recognised by the `book` class, but as you are giving it as a global option (the optional argument to `\documentclass`), it is available to all of the packages you load. It *is* recognised by `scrextend`, so it gets applied.

In contrast, when you make a class, the option `fontsize=14pt` is no longer on the global list, it's now *purely* passed to `book`, which doesn't recognise it, and as a result a warning is issued. You need to pass the option here to the package that actually needs it, so

```latex
\RequirePackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend}
```

Comment: BTW, you are mixing up `14pt` and `14bp`: these are not the same

Comment: Thanks for answering. I made`14pt` everywhere.